# Class Table Inheritance. How many tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm designing a data model for the product's catalog. There are 1600 categories of products in my project. Each category can have it's own specific attributes. I want to use Class Table Inheritance (CTI) for that, but I have to create 1600 tables. Isn't it too much? Have anybody ever used so many tables for such a task?

P.S. I know the EAV pattern and how to implement it, but I want to keep a referencial integrity, data types and so on. Moreover, I think CTI is less complicated than EAV.

Comment: Not an easy task.  SQL does not know the concept of Inheritance.

Comment: I think I will use Doctrine ORM for that. I'm a bit confused about 1600 tables. Is it too much and extremely hard to maintain?

Comment: Thousands of identical tables is messier, slower, etc, than one table with an extra column.  There are many questions on the forum that discuss aspects of that.  Or would your tables all have different columns?

Comment: Each table will have it's own columns. U've thought about one big table, it  will have too many columns.

Comment: Then you will have a maintenance nightmare, for which there is not good alternative.